# wget only download the index.html

Tags: wget

hi guys i want to get video from this site (https://5sep.zetfix.online/films/burja/) but wget only downloads index.html what is my mistake?

`wget -r --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --page-requisites --span-hosts --convert-links --no-directories --directory-prefix=output -e robots=off --header="Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7" --header="Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7"  --header="Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" --header="Referer: https://5sep.zetfix.online/films/poltora-dnja/"  –wait 5 –randomwait   https://5sep.zetfix.online/films/burja/`

Comment: I don't see `-r` (recursive download) anywhere near the command line

Comment: Thanks for the note, I've corrected the post.

Comment: wget does not interpret the website which would be needed to extract the address of the video. Remember: The website you see isn't a monolithic thing but consists of multiple files (images, ...) that the browser assembles into a whole. So you need a tool that interprets the site. [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/) can do this and works on some sites other than YouTube. Might be worth to try. But check first whether your jurisdiction allows what you're trying. The other alternative: Grab the URL yourself by looking at the source of the site.

Comment: @aha 
yes, I can track where the video comes from (this is a different domain) . Also, if I download the page in google chrome, I can get the address of the video. I'm trying to automate this process. maybe i need to try headless browser

Comment: Maybe you also need `-p` for page requisites, such as images and videos (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supplying a header which tells the remote that you accept gzipped input:

> --header="Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br"

However, wget does not seem to appreciate when it gets actual gzip response - saves that response to index.html as gzipped stream and does not extract any further links.

If you remove that parameter, actual recursive downloading begins.

Comment: ingeniously, I could not defeat the 404 error for a long time, it only happened after I gave all the headers as a user. I took your advice and it works!